# Why is this function not working properly, when added to a hook?

Tags: hooks

### Situation

I would like to have a function, that when called, creates a new file/buffer in a specific directory, indepent of the current directory.
But with the same file name as the current file that the buffer is visiting.

So I created the following:

```
(defun change-to-foobar-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (setq buffer-temp-name (buffer-name))
    (kill-this-buffer)
    (find-file (concat "C:\\foobar\\" buffer-temp-name)))
```

This works great.

When I have the buffer `foobar.el` in directory `C:\another-dir`, and I call `change-to-foobar-directory`, then I get the buffer
`C:\foobar\foobar.el`. The difference is that I'm editing a buffer in another directory (`C:\foobar`).

### Problem

This solution works great so far. When I add that function to a hook, for example:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'change-to-foobar-directory)
```

And when I'm in the file `another-file.c`, I create a new buffer `foobar.el` with the Evil command `:e foobar.el` (which stands for edit the file foobar.el in the same directory of buffer, even when the file doesn't exist yet, then a new buffer will be created).

Because the `emacs.lisp-mode` gets activated, the function `change-to-foobar-directory` should be called.

But I get the same file `another-file.c` instead editing the file/buffer `C:\foobar\foorbar.el`. So it seems with the hook, `change-to-foobar-directory` will not work properly. I'm not sure what caused this. When I call that command interactively, it will work properly.

Any idea what caused this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dunno what Evil might change in the picture (try without Evil, to see if there is a difference).

But if you are interested in the buffer name of a buffer visiting a file then what you should use is `buffer-file-name`, not just `buffer-name`. Specifically, `(file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))`, if you want only the non-dir part. (`buffer-name` is for any buffer; `buffer-file-name` returns `nil` if the buffer is not visiting a file. This lets you conditionally *not* try to, for example, use the name of a non-file buffer as a file name.)

Similarly, do not use `concat` for file names. Instead, use `expand-file-name` with the directory you want to use as the second arg: `(expand-file-name buffer-temp-name "C:/foobar/")` (and no need to use MS Windows directory separators.

Also, use `let` to bind the relative file name, instead of just `setq` (unless, for some reason, you have a global variable of that name and you want to change its value).

Finally, if you want to kill the buffer and then find a file to replace it, just use **`find-alternate-file`**. This will take care of the problem you are experiencing, and that @nanny and @Stefan have pointed to.

```lisp
(defun change-to-foobar-directory ()
  (interactive)
  "..."
  (let* ((filebuf               (buffer-file-name))
         (relname               (and filebuf  (file-name-nondirectory filebuf)))
         (emacs-lisp-mode-hook  ()))
    (when filebuf
     (find-alternate-file (expand-file-name relname "C:/foobar/")))))
```

*Suggestion:* Spend a little time with the Elisp manual, node [File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html) and its subnodes. You'll appreciate it.

Comment: Your solution didn't worked, got the message `"Note: file is write protected"` and the buffer name is a concenation of previous directory path and new path. However your code seems faulty (Sorry, I consider you as the master in Lisp) I would like to learn from it: 1. What is the difference between `buffer-file-name` and `buffer-name`? 2. Why prefering the `expand-file-name` above `concat`, while the result would be the same? 3.  Your project is discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3nczl4/oneononeemacs_a_project_to_make_emacs_more/).

Comment: `buffer-file-name` is only for buffers visiting files. If used in another buffer (not associated with a file) it returns `nil`, which is probably the problem you are encountering. In that case, you would need to specify what behavior you want, for such a buffer. OK, you want to kill it. But do you really want to open a file with the same name as that non-file buffer (e.g. `*scratch*` or whatever)? Not clear to me what the aim is in this case.

Comment: `expand-file-name` and the other file-name manipulating functions are designed for, well, manipulating file names. They can be used in multiple contexts, including different platforms and remote hosts. `concat` sees only strings, not file names. Again, consider reading some of the doc I pointed you to.

Comment: (This Q&A have nothing to do with [OneOnOneEmacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs), which you referenced.)

Comment: I've edited the post so that the function should now be a no-op if the current buffer is not visiting a file. In the absence of a clear spec of what behavior you want in that case, this seems reasonable.

Comment: Drew, thanks for your helpful comments. I have read the documentation about file names. And your function still doesn't work, by the way. I end up in the **lose** buffer, and I got the message `File mode specification error: (error: "Selecting deleted buffer").` Another suggestion?

Comment: Provide a recipe of what you're doing, starting from `emacs -Q`. Include info about what buffer you are starting in, what other buffers exist, etc. Or `M-x debug-on-entry change-to-foobar-directory` and step through the debugger, to see what the problem is. The `**lose**` buffer is from `find-alternate-file`, which should not get called unless the buffer you are in is visiting a file. Start with a simple case of a file in the same dir - see if the problem has to do with which file you try to find.

Comment: Drew, thanks for willing to help me out, I made a screencast to illustrate my problem with your code snippet: http://i.imgur.com/Ph6Hi5a.gifv And `M-x debug-on-entry`, then typing `change-to-foobar-directory`, gives me no results. I use GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) by the way.
of 2015-07-25 on KAEL

Comment: Yes, because `find-alternate-file` calls `find-file`, which itself applies the mode hook. You can work around that by binding `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` to `nil` in the same `let`. But really you should not be calling a function that visits a file from within a mode hook - you will always run into the same problem, since file-visiting functions invoke mode hooks. What you probably want to do is use `find-file-hook` instead, and test in for the mode in the hook function.

Comment: Thanks Drew, changing the emacs-lisp-mode-hook to nil did do the trick. I think that file-visiting functions that invoke mode hooks would not be a problem, because I intend to use it only for WSD-mode, and all WSD-files are stored in a map, hence the hook.

Answer (score 5):

In your problematic case, when you're visiting foobar.el, Emacs does the following *in this order*:

- fetch foobar.el into a new buffer.
- initialize the major mode (including running the hooks).
- display the buffer in the selected window.

So your hook will kill the foobar.el buffer, create a new foobar.el buffer at the new location.  At this point, you should get an "infinite-recursion error" here since that `find-file` will also run the `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`.  If you somehow avoid that error, then you bump into another error which is that right after your hook has finished, the third step ("display the buffer in the selected window") may cause yet more grief (either signalling an error because that buffer has been killed in the mean time, or displaying some other buffer in its stead).

Answer (score 2):

Hooks get called as the [last step in a mode's initialization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html).

> And when I'm in the file another-file.c, I create a new buffer foobar.el

So you create that buffer, `foobar.el`, `emacs-lisp-mode` gets enabled in the buffer, and then its hooks are run. One of its hooks is your function `change-to-foobar-directory`. Your function calls `kill-this-buffer`. But what's `this-buffer` at this time? `foobar.el`.

The function is working perfectly fine, it simply has a logical error. Instead, try:

```lisp
(defun change-to-foobar-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (setq buffer-temp-name (buffer-name))
    (kill-buffer (other-buffer))
    (find-file (concat "C:\\foobar\\" buffer-temp-name)))
```

Or see Drew's answer for a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately, wIth your snippet, the changed function didn't worked out. I got the error: `Error while checking syntax automatically: (file-error "Opening output file" "Invalid argument" "C:/foobar/foobar.el<foobar>")`.

While the folder foobar exists. So it worked right there in your situation?